# Set VBA Range Variable to A Set of Cells in Another Workbook

Tags: excel, vba

**Question**: I have workbook say workbook A in which I have inserted a module containing a VBA macro. Within that macro I have declared a set of ranges - for example, dim rngName as Range. The macro opens a file in a specified folder, I do not know the name of the this file. I want to set rngName to a range from the file I just opened. How do I do that ?

---

Sample code I what I have written:

```
Public Sub Foo()

Dim rngName As Range
Dim lastRow as Long 

Code Open A Workbook  'and so this should be the active workbook after opening ?

With ActiveWorkbook  
  LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
  Set rngName = Range("A1" & LastRow).Cells

End With

End Sub
```

---

I do know the variable lastRow is assigned the correct value. Note my script does not produce an error however nothing is assigned to the ranges.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Do not assume that the newly opened workbook is the active workbook.  Assign it to a variable.
2. You need to designate a worksheet.
3. should be .Range("A1:A" & lastRow)

---

```
Public Sub Foo()
    Dim wkb As Workbook
    Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("filename")

    With wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
        Dim lastRow As Long
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        Dim rngName As Range
        Set rngName = .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).Cells
    End With

    Debug.Print rngName.Address
End Sub
```

Comment: why was it necessary, from a programming perspective, to declare the ranges within the with statement ?

Comment: @user3195446 it is not required, it is a personal preference as it allows me to see the declarations next to the assignations.  When the code gets long I do not need to scroll up and down checking declarations against the assignation.

Comment: It is worth noting that I have to use: lastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row if I declare lastRow within the with block.  Otherwise  the "." before the Range throws an error - "object property does not support ..."